# Save image from byte data with python gdal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, gis, gdal

I'm retrieving a Sentinel-2 image with metadata from an ArcGIS REST API server. It comes as a byte string. I currently first write the data to a tif-file with f.write(). Then I open it with imageio and later save it as a geoTIFF with gdal.

I would like to save the image directly as a geoTIFF with gdal. But I haven't figured out how to extract the image as a numpy array directly from the byte data, or how to use gdal to write the image directly from the byte data. I use Python 3.8 and Windows 10.

```
import requests
from imageio import imread
from osgeo import gdal

response = requests.get(im_url, auth=auth)  # call image url
im_binary = response.content  # the image in binary format
im_newpath = 'testimage.tif'
with open(im_newpath, 'wb') as f: 
     f.write(im_binary)

print(type(im_binary))

print(im_binary[0:50])
```

returns:

```
<class 'bytes'>

b'II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00X\x02\x00\x00\x01\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x90\x01\x00\x00\x02\x01\x03\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\n\x01\x00\x00\x03\x01\x03\x00'
```

My attempts to decode the data has so far given bad results.

```
decoded = im_binary.decode('utf_16')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 364-365: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

Ignoring or replacing the errors gives various non-nunmeric characters. Any advice?

Comment: I fail to see, why you assume, that TIFF image binary data  are UTF-16 decodable. (UTF only considers *text*). For tiff an image library as [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is required.

Comment: I didn't know that UTF only considers text, so that's a good point. But what I'd mostly like to do is still do write the bytes data directly to a geocoded image. pillow doesn't support more than 3 bands, and the data has 13 bands, which is why I want to use gdal. But I don't know how to use write bytes data to an image with gdal.

Comment: I still fail to see, what you mean by *decode* then. If the data is already a valid tiff image writing it to the file should work as decribed above. Reading is not covered by any part of the code above, but it seems, that you simply need to call `imread()` with the *filename* (not the raw data).

Comment: I would have preferred a cleaner solution than to write the file (to a tif), read it, and then write it again (to a geoTIFF). In my mind, a cleaner solution would be to write the requests output directly to a geoTIFF. But I haven't found a way to do that. If I don't have to decode anything in the process, that would be great.

Comment: Try [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) for reading numpy arrays from your encoded bytes: `image_array = imagecodecs.tiff_decode(im_binary)`

Answer (score 1):

To summary my comments and insights from answers:

Nothing seems wrong with the approach. Since images consist of pure binary data, there is no use of UTF-decoding routines.

I don't understand the necessity for any other decoding. What is received looks like fine TIFF data.

While writing to a temporary file just to be able to pass the file to another library seems clumsy, it is a robust and clean way to proceed. Probably the physical file can be avoided by using a [StringIo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#string-io) instance, but since this requires the full image data to be held in memory, it may not work for huge images. (I'm not sure, how the URL to be passed tom `imread()` has to look like in that case - seems one more argument to use file instead).